# Realm 2-way binding in Xamarin Forms UWP throws exception

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp, realm

I am working on Xamarin forms project targeting iOS/Droid/UWP. We are building the app in a reactive manner and use direct model bindings. For instance, let's imagine we have the following code

```
public class Product : RealmObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static string LocalPath = "";
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var realm = Realm.GetInstance(Path.Combine(LocalPath, "RealmSample.realm"));
            realm.Write(() =>
            {
                realm.Add(new Product()
                {
                    Name = "Test"
                });
            });
            BindingContext = realm.All<Product>().FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

And the following xaml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="RealmBindingSample.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Entry 
            Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Nothing is special in here. And this code works just fine on iOS/Droid and the data is persisted as soon as value of the Entry changes. However, on UWP as soon as the page is loaded I get the following exception

> Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction.

Is this expected behavior in UWP? Am I missing something.

I have installed the Realm.Database nuget version 3.4.0, and the `FodyWeavers.xml` files are present in all of the projects.

Comment: I created a code sample with RealM version 4.0 nuget , and it works well. This is test [sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/RealMTest).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT thanks, it was exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a reply to this issue in the [official github issues](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1869?fbclid=IwAR09qKZmttkA6VPjU7ARY9CbJSVsSA7oWVXbtY6ajOQlh1qkhunwkntGDLo#issuecomment-502482760) of the Realm.Net library.

> Two way data binding doesn't work with UWP with Realm 3.4.0 because
>   it's a netstandard 1.4 library and the classes needed to implement
>   automatic transactions were only added in netstandard 2.0. You can
>   upgrade Realm to 4.0.0, but be advised that that will require
>   upgrading your UWP project to target netstandard 2.0.

The problem was in the version of the Realm nuget package I was using. I used Realm.Database nuget latest 3.4.0 version. As soon as I replaced the package with Realm nuget version 4.0.0 everything worked just fine.